# How do I solve these problems using the intersection of the union and other event properties?

Tags: probability

A product X might show 2 types of manufacturing defects, A and B, if P(A)=0,1, P(B)=0,2 and P(A intersection B) = 0.05. formalize and compute the probability that a unit has:

1. at least one of the defects
2. defect A but not defect B
3. none of the defects
4. just one of the defects A and B.

Comment: You got already one down grade because I assume the formulation of your question is not very precise. Also the question itself is very trivial. Please draw two intersecting circles on a sheet of paper. One circle represents A, the other circle represents B. The intersection represents A and B which has a probability of 0.05. So write the 0.05 inside the intersection. I leave the rest to you to fill the two circles with the remaining probabilities and the part outside of both circles (event 3 of your question). You can do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are told $\Pr(A), \Pr(B)$ and $\Pr(A\cap B)$.  This is enough information to learn everything else requested about how $A$ and $B$ interact.

The following facts will be useful:

- Inclusion-Exclusion (*for two sets*): $\Pr(X\cup Y) = \Pr(X)+\Pr(Y)-\Pr(X\cap Y)$
- Total probability: $\Pr(X) = \Pr(X\cap Y)+\Pr(X\cap Y^c)$
- De Morgan's Laws: $(X\cap Y)^c = X^c\cup Y^c$  and  $(X\cup Y)^c = X^c\cap Y^c$

and then just basic definitions and the ability to rewrite each of the statements in terms of sets (*For example "Exactly one of the defects" corresponds to $(A^c\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$*)

> 1) At least one defect: $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$.  2) Defect A but not defect B: $\Pr(A\cap B^c)=\Pr(A)-\Pr(A\cap B)$.  3) None of the defects: $\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)=1-\Pr(A\cup B) = 1 - \Pr(A)-\Pr(B)+\Pr(A\cap B)$.  4) Exactly one of the defects: $\Pr(A^c\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap B^c) = (\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B))+(\Pr(A)-\Pr(A\cap B))$ or equivalently $\Pr(A\cup B) - \Pr(A\cap B)$.

Comment: oh thanks, i understand everything. excuse me for the time taken away.